# What type of paint do I need for Bannisters and Windowsill?

Tags: paint

I have decorators coming next month who will be repainting the hand rail for the stairs and a windowsill. What type of paint do I need for these? The existing handrail looks varnished and is Mahogany in colour. I want either Rosewood or Oak but really have no idea what I should be looking for, a lady in B&Q recommended Ronseal exterior Rosewood woodstain but where I've tested this it doesn't seem very hard wearing, would it also need Varnish on top?
The windowsill is the same question, I want to try changing it to Rosewood rather than white but what do I need, a paint or a woodstain?

Rail
[image: Stair hand rail]

Windowsill
[image: Windowsill]

Comment: Why don't you ask the decorators for advice? They're the professionals that you're paying for their expertise... In general, though, you'll want _interior_ finishes, not _exterior_. (It does appear that this is an interior.) If the railings are stained, your decorators should know how to match the stain (they should mix up several samples and provide them so you can make the final choice), and they should have a good recommendation for a top coat (varnish, poly, etc.) for protection.

Comment: Additionally, there is _no way_ someone would be able to recommend a color match for you over the internet. Between the issues in color capture by your camera (phone) and the rendition on our monitors, I guarantee it will look different to what's physically in your house. If you're looking for a true color match, take a sample of the existing color to a paint store and have them put it in their computer system that will figure out the color & specify a mix to exactly duplicate it.